# Dont let world texture affect lighting of objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, world

I've done exactly what they did here to make the background show as a COLOR (for transparent objects in my scene, etc) but not be EMISSIVE, so it doesnt reflect off onto glossy/diffuse objects in scene:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiZ087M-LjdAhX8wMQHHdZtDN8QFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F60625%2Fnon-emitting-background-in-cycles&usg=AOvVaw2R5w_1ujiDdRrmro8Dq4Fp

Yet I still have definite reflection here. Did I miss something? I have transparent turned off in film.. not sure where else

Comment: I replicated what they did in their answer on the scene of my last answer on your question and was able to replicate it: https://imgur.com/a/zkAKUgO. Please share your .blend if possible or make a version of it that shows the problem, but is smaller. We can't know what you missed if we don't know what you did

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BvBUZe-6pnNnoYfRr3sl6RbOz8-gNnrK/view?usp=sharing @WhatAMesh

Comment: Change your connection to the mix node, one socket will show in the camera the other in reflections.